# How to create and write to files indefinitely in Python?

Tags: python

I have to make a script which creates a certain amount of subfolders in each main folder (dir1, dir2, and dir3). Then, inside of each subfolder, there has to be files (.txt.for example) been created constantly until I (the user) decides to stop the program. Right now, I can create subfolders (from 0 to 99) in each main folder, but I'm not sure how to create the .txt files. Any suggestions or ideas would be very much appreciated. Here's my code:

```
import os

folders = ["dir1", "dir2", "dir3"]
count = 0

for folder in folders:

    for count in range(100):
        subfolder = str(count)
        newfolder =  os.makedirs(os.path.join(folder, subfolder))
```

I'm trying to do something like this

```
with open("%s/01.txt" %count, "wa") as fh
```

so it goes to each subdirectory and create the file

Answer (score -1):

You can simply open and write nothing. For example:

```
with open("01.txt", "w") as fh:
    fh.write("")
```

This means that you can also write stuff in the future, if necessary. It may not be necessary to .write(), but it improves readability.

Comment: I believe you do not even need to `.write`, you could just `pass` as `open` will create a file which doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok I'll check that, but writing nothing makes it read better: a person reviewing the code can see exactly what it does